# Calculate AUC-ROC and AUC-PRC for an LSTM Model

Tags: classification, keras, scikit-learn, lstm, auc

I have the following simple Bidirectional LSTM model for a binary classification task:

```
      MODEL = Sequential([
          Masking(mask_value = -1.0, input_shape = (None, 36)),
          Bidirectional(LSTM(units = 200, return_sequences = False, dropout = 0.20), input_shape = (None, 36), merge_mode = 'concat'),
          Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')
      ])

      MODEL.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = METRICS)

      HISTORY = MODEL.fit(Xtrain[train], ytrain[train], epochs = 32) # class_weight = weights, if using weights add this to .fit()

      PREDICTED = MODEL.predict(Xtrain[test])
```

I have been looking at some code where people calculate the AUC-ROC and AUC-PRC and what I see is them using the `.predict_proba()` function and also using only the positive class predictions to calculate the AUCs, like so: `predicted = predicted[:,1]`.

I have calculated the AUCs like so:

```
from sklearn.metrics import auc, roc_acu_score

roc_auc_score(ytrain[test], PREDICTED)
fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(ytrain[test], PREDICTED) # to plot curve

precision, recall, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(ytrain[test], PREDICTED)
auc(recall, precision)
```

Given that my model predicts a single array of probabilities, am I calculating these metrics correctly?

Thanks in advance!